# Is it possible to avoid smoking when seasoning a cast iron pan after using it for deep-frying?

Tags: oil, cleaning, cast-iron

I have a cast-iron dutch oven similar to [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00063RWYI), which I infrequently use for deep frying. I tend to use what tends to be generically described here in the UK as "vegetable oil" for the deep frying, which I understand is often a blend of oils.

When I'm done with the deep frying, I filter and pour out most of the oil for potential reuse, but there is always a thin film inside the pot. My understanding for cast iron surfaces has always been that I should *not* use dishsoap or similar on the pot before putting it away, so instead what I tend to do is wipe off as much oil as possible using a paper towel, and then put in the oven as hot as possible (250C/480F) to give it a 'free' season.

However, this generates a lot of smoky smells (even inside the oven with the lid on), and my partner finds it deeply unpleasant.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I be using a different oil for the frying? Alternatively, is there another way to clean the residual oil off the pan before putting it away?

Answer (score 1):

You never want to get **all** the oil off, which is why a bath in Fairy Liquid is not considered a good idea.
You can, however, get *most* of it off with hot water & salt & a scrub round with your dish-washing brush. This has for centuries been considered 'good enough'.

After which, a quick heat up back on the stove top until you're sure it's completely dry & you can put it back in the rack (once cooled if your storage demands it).

Smoking out your partner is not conducive to good relationships, nor really a 'better' non-stick surface. Normal usage should be enough to preserve both ;)